# Remove timestamps that are close to each other or within threshold in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, timestamp

Problem:
I have a lot of datapoints that are too close to each other in terms of timestamps meaning that when I manipulate the data, I am oversampling.

What I need:
For each element in the dataframe, I need to drop all elements that are within a 5 second range from it. This means that the first row is the one I am using and the subsequent rows that are within 5 seconds need to be dropped. This is what I have right now:

```
test_df = test_df.sort_values(by='timestamp').reset_index(drop=True)
for i in range(0, len(test_df)):
    currentTimestamp = test_df.timestamp.loc[i]
    temp_row = test_df.loc[i]
    temp_5_secs = add_ms(currentTimestamp, 5000)
    test_df = test_df[(test_df.timestamp) >= temp_5_secs].reset_index(drop=True)
    test_df = test_df.append(temp_row, ignore_index=True)
    test_df = test_df.sort_values(by='timestamp').reset_index(drop=True)


def add_ms(timestamp, ms):
    return int(timestamp) + 1000000* ms
```

### but its giving me the following error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/local/home/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
354                 try:
--> 355                     return self._range.index(new_key)
356                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 235 is not in range

This is a sample dataframe:

```
index timestamp        value
0   1675434673166538783 14.62
1   1675434684419325010 14.62
2   1675434684420505291 14.62
3   1675434673164456809 14.63
4   1675434700772654637 14.50
```

Summary, for each of the timestamp elements in the dataframe, remove the subsequent elements that are within 5 second range from that element. Remove by dropping the rows. Do this for each element so we know for a fact that the result will be that there will be no rows that timestamps are less than 5 seconds from each other.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish what you are trying to do is as follows:

Given the sample df.

1. sort to ensure timestamps are ascending
2. create a list of rows to drop
3. drop the indexes.

to perform these steps create the following functions.

```
def mask_stamp(k: list, time_incr: int)-> list[bool]:
    # return a list of bool values where True implies drop row
    last_time = 0
    delta_t = time_incr * 1000000000
    rslt = []
    for tstmp in k:
        if tstmp > last_time:
            rslt.append(False)
            last_time = tstmp + delta_t
        else:
            rslt.append(True)
    return rslt  

def filter_timestamps(dfx: pd.DataFrame, time_inc:int)-> None:
    # return df with timestamps filtered by time increment
    drp_list = mask_stamp(dfx['timestamp'].to_list(), time_inc)
    for i in range(len(drp_list)):
        if drp_list[i]:
            dfx.drop(index= i, inplace= True)
```

Then perform the following:

```
df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True) 
filter_timestamps(df, 5)
```

This yields:

```
    timestamp   value
0   1675434673164456809 14.63
2   1675434684419325010 14.62
4   1675434700772654637 14.50
```